# Is there any way to get rid of the grey box surrounding objects from vse in final render?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

[image]When using the video editor, any object that overlaps another in the video shows up with a grey box around it in the final render as well as the viewport. Is there any way to get rid of this? I've attached an image of the faint box in case it may help. Keep in mind the image is simply of a white box, over a white background, there's not line in the actual image, this entire strip should be white.[image]

Comment: can u please show us an example blend file or screenshots what you mean? i am not sure whether i understood what you mean...

Comment: Of course. I'll add another screenshot, but how would you suggest adding a blend file? I've never added one to a post here before.

Comment: @Chris updated.

Comment: thank you! you are totally right and i have no idea why this happens and how to stop it ;(

Comment: @Chris Well, thank you for your time anyway!